# Spring Cloud Data Flow Task Persist Arguments Between Executions

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I'm experimenting with SCDF and successfully running Spring Batch Jobs as Tasks. But I'm having a issue with Task Arguments persisting. It seems that each time I need to execute the Task I should provide it with the command line arguments.

In my use case I need the command line arguments to be set once and for all for a Task.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I ended up using the Parameters instead of the Arguments.

[image]

1. First I created a Spring Batch with multiple CommandLineRunners (2 in my case), one for the production which will use the "application properties" that will be overridden by SCDF parameters, and one for the other environments (DEV, ...) that will get launched through simple command line arguments or through API.
2. First CommandLineRunner:

   @Component
   @Slf4j
   @Profile("prod")
   public class ProdJobCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

   ```
   @Value("${jobname}")
   private String jobName;

   @Value("${argument1}")
   private String argument1;

   @Value("${argument2}")
   private String argument2;

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context;

   @Autowired
   private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

   @Override
   public void run(String... args) {

       log.info("Begin Launching Job with Args {}", Arrays.asList(args));
       log.error("JOB NAME: " + jobName);

       if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Arrays.asList(args))) {

           JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();

           jobParametersBuilder.addString("argument1", argument1);
           jobParametersBuilder.addString("argument2", argument2);

           try {
               Job job = (Job) context.getBean(jobName);

               jobLauncher.run(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());

           } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
               log.error("Exception ", e);
           }
       }
       log.info("End Launching Job with Args {}", Arrays.asList(args));
   }
   ```

   }
3. Second CommandLineRunner:

   @Component
   @Slf4j
   @Profile("!prod")
   public class DefaultJobCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

   ```
   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context;

   @Autowired
   private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

   @Override
   public void run(String... args) {

       log.info("Begin Launching Job with Args {}", Arrays.asList(args));

       if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Arrays.asList(args))) {

           Map<String, String> params = parseJobArgs(args);
           JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();

           if (Boolean.parseBoolean(params.getOrDefault("force_restart", "false"))) {
               jobParametersBuilder.addString("force_restart", LocalDateTime.now().toString());
           }

           try {

               String jobName = params.get("job_name");

               log.info("JOB NAME: " + jobName);

               Job job = (Job) context.getBean(jobName);

               jobLauncher.run(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());

           } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
               log.error("Exception ", e);
           }
       }
       log.info("End Launching Job with Args {}", Arrays.asList(args));
   }

   private Map<String, String> parseJobArgs(String[] args) {
       Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

       Arrays.asList(args).forEach(arg -> {
           String key = StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(arg.split("=")[0]);
           String value = StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(arg.split("=")[1]);

           params.put(key, value);
       });
       return params;
   }
   ```

   }
4. Import the app in SCDF, say for example **TESTAPP**

[image]

3. Create multiple Tasks, depending on how many use cases you have, using the same imported app
4. For each task when launched for the first time, set the Parameters you have following the naming convention:
   app. "APP_NAME". "property key"="property value"

In this case for example it will be: **app.TESTAPP.jobname=JOB_NAME**

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. The task application's `arguments` have to be passed every time the task application gets launched as the command line arguments aren't meant to be propagated between subsequent task launches.

Only the task `deployment` properties you pass as `Parameters` above are designed to be persisted and re-used as you launch the subsequent task launches. These deployment properties also include the task `application` properties (the ones that are passed with the `app.` prefix) along with the platform-specific `deployer` properties (the properties with the `deployer.` prefix).

Given these design aspects, I agree there could be use cases (like yours) to pass the same arguments between task launches. Hence, I suggest you create a story with your specific cases [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues) and we'll revisit the design to scope out this.

Comment: Thank you, that's the road I ended up taking, but got me to creating multiple Command Line Runners depending on the environment, I will add a response here so people can profit from it. And one more thing, the parameters once set and the Task launched for the first time, if I modify them the don't completely override the previous ones, the are appended to them in the list. And I will for sure open a story for this use case.